# 404 Error on React deployment with https but works on http (used GoDaddy)

Tags: reactjs, https, deployment, create-react-app, github-pages

I'm trying to transfer my gh-pages website to a custom domain I purchased through GoDaddy. This is the DNS configuration: 
[image]

I changed my `package.json` file to have:

```
"homepage": "https://www.juliesong.me",
```

and put my Github pages setting to be: 
[image]

After deploying with `npm run deploy`, it seems to appear on www.juliesong.me but it says the connetion to the site is not secure. I think it has something to do with http vs https but I'm not exactly sure. If I type in https://juliesong.me, it gives me a 404 error like the following:
[image]

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks:)

Comment: It can take up to an hour for your site to become available over HTTPS after you configure your custom domain

Comment: Have you added CNAME file in the root of your repository?

Comment: @HeisAif how do you add the file?